# A split infinitive de-emphasises the verb?

Tags: difference

At about 60%-way down the page http://chronicle.com/article/50-Years-of-Stupid-Grammar/25497:

> ...But what interests me here is the descriptive claim about stress on the adverb. It is completely wrong.
>
> Tucking the adverb in before the verb actually de-emphasizes the adverb, so a sentence like "The dean's statements tend to completely polarize the faculty" places the stress on polarizing the faculty. The way to stress the completeness of the polarization would be to write, "The dean's statements tend to polarize the faculty completely."

I don't perceive the differences; what's the lesson here? Don't these two sentences convey the same meaning? Either way, isn't the polarisation of the faculty complete?

Answer (score 3):

Pullum is not speaking of meaning but of *emphasis*—what is the focal term in the sentence?—so to understand Pullum's argument you must read with your ears, not your eyes.

The strictly verbal meaning of a sentence will have very different pragmatic meanings in different discourse situations; and writers sensitive to the discourse situation will frame their sentences so their syntax elicits the prosodic emphasis which their situations require.

In Pullum's example, for instance, it may be that the faculty as a whole previously took only a dispassionate and scholarly attitude toward the issue which the Dean addressed, and the Dean’s statements aroused their ideological and professional concerns, dividing them into opposed camps. In that case, the ‘new information’ in the sentence, the key point it seeks to convey, resides in *polarized*, and the ‘completeness’ of the polarization is of secondary interest.

On the other hand, it may be the case that there was some degree of polarization before the Dean weighed in—perhaps there was a small number of professors on each side of the issue, but most faculty were indifferent—and that the effect of his statement was to compel every professor to take a stand on the issue. In that case, *polarization* is ‘old information’ and the ‘new information’ resides in *completely*.

Pullum’s argument speaks to the different ways a sentence may be organized to realize different emphases. Other things being equal, the strongest position in an English sentence, the position where ‘new information’ is placed, is the right end of the main clause. Placing the single adverb after the verb (and its complement—English syntax dislikes interrupting that collocation) provides a stress point further to the right. The prosodic contour of the sentence—the rise and fall of stress- and pitch-emphasis—will rise toward a peak on *completely*.

```
      °  ′       ′   °     ′ ° °    °   ′ ° °   °   ″   °
    The Dean’s statements polarize the faculty completely.
```

In contrast, placing the adverb *completely* before the verb puts the verb (with its complement) as far to the right as it can go, so it occupies the more emphatic position.

```
      °  ′       ′   °     °   ′   °  ″ °  °   °   ′ °  °
    The Dean’s statements completely polarize the faculty.
```

The adverb is weakened even further when it interrupts a *to* + infinitive construction, because the ‘local’ effect—the need for emphasis to rise from unstressed *to* toward the infinitive it marks—puts the adverb is a destressed position and reinforces the ‘global’ sentence-long prosodic contour.

```
      °  ′       ′   °     ′    °  °   °   °  ″ ° °    °   ′ °  °
    The Dean’s statements tend to completely polarize the faculty.
```

Comment: +1. Thank you. Would you please enlarge on your last paragraph? Why's the adverb weakened? What 'emphasis...rise[s] from **to** toward the infinitive'? I don't detect this emphasis. What's the 'prosodic contour'?

Comment: Will you please to respond  in your answer, and not as a comment?

Comment: @LePressentiment Done. Look at the stress notation.